# How do I use the replyTo option parameter of replyAll()?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

### Scenario

- Create a script that can send a email as per user selection on google spread sheet.
- When user going to send email first time in a day must send a new email.
- If going to send second time check subject line if already exists then must be `replyAll` to that email.

### Attempted code

```
if (threads[0]) {
  threads[0].replyAll(emailBody, {
    // 'replyTo': emailAddress, (Removed due to issue with Gmail)
    'cc': emailAddressCC,
    'bcc': emailAddressBCC,
    'htmlBody': emailBody
    });
} else {
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailBody, {
  // 'replyTo': emailAddress, 
  'cc': emailAddressCC,
  'bcc': emailAddressBCC,
  'htmlBody': emailBody
}
```

Link to full script: [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Jaydeep1434/c160c2302ca09663fc5d2f298f79f035)

- This script creates a menu `onOpen` "Send Mail".
- So, when user selects some area from sheet and click on "Send Mail" button it calls `funShowAlert()` and sends an email.

### Issue

- When I attempt to add the recipient's email to `replyTo`, gmail returns an error.

> Question: Is it possible to use `replyAll` without the `replyTo` option parameter, and am I doing something wrong with `replyTo` ?

Comment: See [replyAll() documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#replyAll(String,Object))

Comment: @Altigraph already used but it is not working as `Gmail replyAll` without `replyTo`.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Jaydeep1434/c160c2302ca09663fc5d2f298f79f035

Comment: Please [include code in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in addition to any external sites; also, the code you provided does not include any `replyAll`

Comment: Okay let me update code.

Comment: @downvoters please remember to put a comment so, I can fix it.

Comment: Why did you [delete your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56335147/google-apps-replyall-on-existing-thread-without-replyto) on this exact topic and then just re-ask it? If you didn't get enough attention, that is what a bounty is for.

Comment: @tehhowch because previously I think the question looks like weird. So, remove it and ask second time properly.

And you may get what is actual issue in this question.

And please let me know what is issue if I ask second time ?

Comment: Use the edit button to improve your question; do not delete and re-ask. You still have not included the minimal script here in the question, as required.

Comment: Where is your code? Provide [mre]. Don't link to github

Comment: @Altigraph, tehhowch, TheMaster - I added some code.

Comment: What is the value of `emailAddress` in your code (which again, [should be included in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), not in an external link)? [replyTo is for YOUR Reply-To address](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#replyAll(String)), and will only work for email addresses you could select as a reply-to address for the gmail account sending the message.

Comment: What's the issue? `If I add replyTo it will generate issue for gmail` What issue? 
`If I remove replyTo then, how do I perform replyAll from script ?` The same way you have in your example script provided. You don't need a ``replyTo`` address.  The documentation states `Reply to the sender (using the replyTo address), and all recipients of the last message on this thread,`. The replyTo address here refers to the replyTo address of the sender(not you).

Comment: Still doesn't mention what the error is that Gmail throws. Seems rather important to tell people the error you are having if you want help resolving it!

Comment: Amending the above, I tested with `replyTo` as various emails that I cannot use as an alias, and found Apps Script would actually happily use any of them as the replyTo address. Impossible to say until OP provides the error they see, but possibly bad value/address, or Google blocks you from indicating the recipient's address as replyTo when it is not your alias (the only accounts I have available for testing are already aliases, and they were valid `replyTo`s)

Answer (score 5):

> I am doing something wrong with `replyTo` ?

Yes.

Read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#replyAll(String)) carefully:

> Reply to the sender (using the replyTo address),

The 'replyTo address' here is referring to the replyTo address in the email to which are you replying. It is made apparent that this is NOT the `replyTo` option parameter by the fact that there is no such parameter passed in the example immediately following it.

`replyTo` as a parameter option is defined in the next entry:

> an email address to use as the default reply-to address (default: the user's email address)

'The user' here being the user the script is running as. This means that the `replyTo` option should be the address you would want the recipient to reply to. Normally when sending via Gmail's web UI, this must be a [Gmail Alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) associated with that account; although some testing with Apps Script indicates that is not necessarily the case.

Your code as is, with replyTo removed, is sufficient.